# How to set timezone for Postgres psql?

Tags: postgresql, timezone, psql

How do I set timezone for psql to something other than my default (US/Central)? Here's what I've tried so far:

```
$ psql
psql (9.1.4, server 9.0.4)
...

$ psql -c 'show timezone'
  TimeZone  
------------
 US/Central

$ psql --set=timezone=US/Eastern -c 'show timezone'
  TimeZone  
------------
 US/Central

$ psql --variable=timezone=US/Eastern -c 'show timezone'
  TimeZone  
------------
 US/Central
```

*Edit*: I don't want to change the server timezone, just the client.

*Edit #2*: I want it in non-interactive mode.

Comment: Changing the timezone should be done using the **SQL** statement `set`, not through psql commands (see Richard's answer)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html) doc says:

```
-v assignment
--set=assignment
--variable=assignment
Perform a variable assignment, like the \set internal command. Note that 
you must separate name and value, if any, by an equal sign on the command line....
```

But with the timezone it does not seem to work, perhaps because because of this:

```
 These assignments are done during a very early stage of start-up, 
 so variables reserved for internal purposes might get overwritten later.
```

So, it seems you must either use the SET command inside psql, or either set the [PGTZ](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-envars.html) environment variable:

```
PGTZ=PST8PDT psql -c 'show timezone'
```

Of course, if you are OK with setting the timezone globally for the user (not just for this individual psql instance), you might set that variable in its `.bashrc` file (if in Linux)

Comment: Note you don't need to export it.  At the bash prompt run: PGTZ=US/Eastern psql -c 'show timezone'

Answer (score 31):

```
psql (9.1.4)
Type "help" for help.

richardh=> show timezone;
 TimeZone 
----------
 GB
(1 row)

richardh=> set timezone='UTC';
SET
richardh=> show timezone;
 TimeZone 
----------
 UTC
(1 row)

richardh=> set timezone='US/Eastern';
SET
richardh=> show timezone;
  TimeZone  
------------
 US/Eastern
(1 row)

richardh=> set timezone='blah';
ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "blah"
```

Comment: Yes, I can do it in interactive mode, but I want non-interactive, i.e. to run with -c.

Comment: Richard, It works for temporarily, when I close the SQL pane then it backs to the old one, can you provide permanent solution

Comment: @chintan, this is really a separate question, but you can use "ALTER USER" or "ALTER DATABASE" to set configuration permanently.

Comment: @ChintanPanchal Use `ALTER DATABASE database_name SET TIMEZONE='zone';` then `SET TIMEZONE='zone';`. It seems to set it permanently for the specified database.

Answer (score 23):

```
ALTER USER postgres SET timezone='Asia/Tokyo' ;
```

Comment: This worked for me with Amazon RDS with no restart required. Thx!

Comment: To change timezone for database: `ALTER DATABASE database_name SET TIMEZONE='zone';` then `SET TIMEZONE='zone';`.

Answer (score 4):

Note many third-party clients have own timezone settings overlapping any Postgres server and\or session settings.

E.g. if you're using 'IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3' (or DataGrips), you should define timezone as:

`'DB source properties' -> 'Advanced' tab -> 'VM Options': -Duser.timezone=UTC+06:00`

otherwise you will see 'UTC' despite of whatever you have set anywhere else.