# How to set timezone for Postgres 9.4 permanently

Tags: postgresql

I'm running Postgres 9.4. Every time I change it it's returning to default GMT after I reboot,

```
> $ psql -c 'show timezone'
```

TimeZone

```
>  US/Central
```

Is there a parameter option to be added in postgres.conf?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11779621/251311

Comment: still dose not answer my question , if i set the time now and restart it will be set back to default

Comment: In that answer there is an advice on how to make it persistent.

Answer (score 26):

You can set `timezone` param into `pgsql/data/postgresql.conf` file:

```
timezone = 'US/Central'
```

and then restart postgresql sever.

Comment: i did that and after restart the same thing reset to GMT .

Comment: Can you check permissions and owner for `postgresql.conf` file. Also make sure you edit right config file, run `sudo -u postgres /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql` and enter `SHOW config_file;`

Comment: Many third-party clients have own timezone session settings overlapping any Postgres server and\or session settings. E.g. if you're using 'IntelliJ IDEA' (or DataGrips), you should define timezone in 'Advanced' tab -> 'VM Options': -Duser.timezone=UTC+06:00 for example.

Comment: Handy: [Where does PostgreSQL store configuration/conf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602450/where-does-postgresql-store-configuration-conf-files)