# Representing a future time in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I’ve been conditioned to store past dates as UTC in a database since that is in fact when the event occurred. For future dates, I would store it with a specific timezone, to avoid changes such as leap seconds or timezone rule changes.

Postgres has `timestamp with timezone`, but under the covers, it stores it as UTC, inferring that the specified timezone is an offset of UTC. If the timezone rules were to change, that would not be reflected in the column.

What is recommended in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Think [of it] like a calendar event. UTC doesn’t make sense for that

It sounds like you want to store a *localtime* with respect to a certain timezone.
In that case, store a `timestamp` (without timezone) and the `timezone` in a separate column.

For example, suppose you want to record an event which will occur at 10 am on Feb 26, 2030 in Chicago
and it must be at 10 am *localtime* regardless of the timezone rule in effect on that date.

If the database stores the timestamp without timezone:

```
unutbu=# select '2030-02-26 10:00:00'::timestamp as localtime, 'America/Chicago' AS tzone;
+---------------------+-----------------+
|      localtime      |      tzone      |
+---------------------+-----------------+
| 2030-02-26 10:00:00 | America/Chicago |
+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Then later, you can find the UTC datetime of the event using

```
unutbu=# select '2030-02-26 10:00:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
+---------------------+
|      timezone       |
+---------------------+
| 2030-02-26 16:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

The query returns the UTC datetime, `2030-02-26 16:00:00`, which corresponds to `2030-02-26 10:00:00` localtime in Chicago.

Using `AT TIME ZONE` **delays the application of the timezone rules** to when the query is made instead of when the `timestamptz` was inserted.

---

Using `AT TIME ZONE` on a `timestamp` localizes the datetime to the given timezone, but *reports* the datetime in the *user's timezone*.
Using `AT TIME ZONE` on a `timestamptz` converts the datetime to the given timezone, then drops the offset, thus returning a `timestamp`.
Above, `AT TIME ZONE` is used twice: first to localize a `timestamp` and next to convert the returned `timestamptz` to a new timezone (UTC). The result is a `timestamp` in UTC.

Here is an example, demonstrating `AT TIME ZONE`'s behavior on `timestamp`s:

```
unutbu=# SET timezone = 'America/Chicago';
unutbu=# SELECT '2030-02-26 10:00:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago';
+------------------------+
|        timezone        |
+------------------------+
| 2030-02-26 10:00:00-06 |
+------------------------+

unutbu=# SET timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
unutbu=# SELECT '2030-02-26 10:00:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago';
+------------------------+
|        timezone        |
+------------------------+
| 2030-02-26 08:00:00-08 |
+------------------------+
```

`2030-02-26 10:00:00-06` and `2030-02-26 08:00:00-08` are the same datetimes but reported in different user timezones. This shows 10am in Chicago is 8am in Los Angeles (using current timezone definitions):

```
unutbu=# SELECT '2030-02-26 10:00:00-06'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles';
+---------------------+
|      timezone       |
+---------------------+
| 2030-02-26 08:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

---

An alternative to using `AT TIME ZONE` twice is to [set the user timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32423037/190597) to `UTC`. Then you could use

```
select localtime AT TIME ZONE tzone
```

Note that when done this way, a `timestamptz` is returned instead of a `timestamp`.

---

Beware that storing localtimes can be problematic because there can be nonexistent times and ambiguous times.
For example, `2018-03-11 02:30:00` is a nonexistent localtime in `America/Chicago`. Postgresql normalizes nonexistent localtimes by assuming it refers to the corresponding time after Daylight Savings Time (DST) has begun (as though someone forgot to set their clock forward):

```
unutbu=# select '2018-03-11 02:30:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
+---------------------+
|      timezone       |
+---------------------+
| 2018-03-11 08:30:00 |
+---------------------+
(1 row)

unutbu=# select '2018-03-11 03:30:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
+---------------------+
|      timezone       |
+---------------------+
| 2018-03-11 08:30:00 |
+---------------------+
(1 row)
```

An example of an ambiguous localtime is `2018-11-04 01:00:00` in `America/Chicago`. It occurs twice due to DST. Postgresql resolves this ambiguity by choosing the later time, after DST has ended:

```
unutbu=# select '2018-11-04 01:00:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
+---------------------+
|      timezone       |
+---------------------+
| 2018-11-04 07:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Notice that this means there is no way to refer to `2018-11-04 06:00:00 UTC` by storing localtimes in the `America/Chicago` timezone:

```
unutbu=# select '2018-11-04 00:59:59'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
+---------------------+
|      timezone       |
+---------------------+
| 2018-11-04 05:59:59 |
+---------------------+
```

Answer (score -2):

*Particularly* if you want to protect yourself from future time zune changes you should use `timestamp with time zone`.

PostgreSQL internally stores the number of microseconds since 2000-01-01 00:00:00, which is safe from time zone changes. If you keep updating your PostgreSQL, it will always display that absolute value correctly for your session time zone.

There is no provision for leap seconds in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score -2):

> For future dates, I would store it with a specific timezone, to avoid changes such as leap seconds or timezone rule changes.

That seems backward. The *main advantage* of UTC over other time zones is that it is *less* prone to unexpected future changes: UTC only introduces leap seconds at known, limited points of the calendar year; and has none of the frequent politically-mandated offset changes.

Storing values in some locally-managed timezone leaves those values more prone (compared with UTC) to arbitrary, unpredictable future changes in meaning.

So, the general recommendation is: Store all time values (whether date, or date+time) as UTC in the database, process them internally as UTC values; and convert to/from a local timezone only at external interfaces.

For PostgreSQL, that means prefer `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Comment: Think like a calendar event. UTC doesn’t make sense for that

Comment: @DanielA.White, thanks. That specific information should modify the question description, then; can you update it to specify what you're using these values for?