# How do I prevent Redshift INSERT datetime from dropping the timezone?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a **`String`** in this format: `2018-11-01T00:00:00-07:00` and I would like to convert it to a `TIMESTAMP` and insert it into a `TIMESTAMP` column. However, when I insert it, it drops the `-07:00` without first converting it to `-00:00`. How do I ensure that it is converted and stored in Redshift properly?

Here is an example:
`select ORIGINAL_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP(ORIGINAL_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM CDW_LANDING.X where id = XXXXXX;`

=> `2018-11-01T00:00:00-07:00   2018-10-31 17:00:00`

The `TO_TIMESTAMP` converts it to `2018-10-31 17:00:00` which is what I want. However, when I insert it, it becomes `2018-11-01 00:00:00` and simply drops the `-07:00`.

Here is the example:

```
insert into cdw_stage.X (ORIG_DT) 
select TO_TIMESTAMP(ORIGINAL_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
from CDW_LANDING.INVOICE where id = XXXXXX;
```

But when I query it with `select ORIG_DT from cdw_landing.X;`, it displays `2018-11-01 00:00:00`. What I would like to see is `2018-10-31 17:00:00` which is what the `TO_TIMESTAMP` function should do.

The `ORIG_DT` in Redshift is in `TIMESTAMP` format. The input date is in `VARCHAR`.

How do I get Redshift to save this correctly? I also added postgres tag because Redshift is based off of postgres. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897691/representing-a-future-time-in-postgresql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`2018-11-01T00:00:00-07:00` is ***not*** a [`timestamp` (`timestamp without time zone`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) literal, strictly speaking. It is a [`timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) literal. This is the root of all pain in your question. The wrong cast to `timestamp` ignores the offset. [The Postgres manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-datetime.html#id-1.5.7.13.19.7)

> In a literal that has been determined to be `timestamp without time zone`, PostgreSQL will silently ignore any time zone indication. That
>   is, the resulting value is derived from the date/time fields in the
>   input value, and is **not adjusted for time zone**.

Bold emphasis mine.

The use of `TO_TIMESTAMP()` can't save you. [The Redshift manual:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_TIMESTAMP.html)

> Formats that include a time zone (`TZ`, `tz`, or `OF`) are not supported as input.

(The same is true in Postgres.)

#### Solution

Cast to `timestamptz` (or use a column of that type to begin with), the rest should fall in place:

```
SELECT cast('2018-11-01T00:00:00-07:00' AS timestamptz);
```

Or:

```
SELECT '2018-11-01T00:00:00-07:00'::timestamptz;
```

[The manual about casting in Redshift.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CAST_function.html)

When an actual `timestamptz` is assigned to a `timestamp` column it is converted according to the current `timezone` setting of the session automatically. If you want a different target timezone, use the `AT TIME ZONE` construct. Details:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

The related answer is for Postgres, but timestamp handling in Redshift (while differing in many other aspects!) is the same. [The Redshift manual:](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/r_Type_conversion.html)

> When converting DATE or TIMESTAMP to TIMESTAMPTZ, DATE or TIMESTAMP
>   are assumed to use the current session time zone. The session time
>   zone is UTC by default. For more information about setting the session
>   time zone, see [timezone](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/r_timezone_config.html).

Comment: Those SQL commands does not work in Redshift but this leads me to the correct answer. The correct solution is to set the format in Redshift as `TIMESTAMPTZ` instead of `TIMESTAMP` and everything works without modification.

Comment: @okysabeni: Cool. The cast should work in Redshift, too. I had a stray `\`` character in the string, that may have mislead you. Added some more.