# How do you set the default Postgresql system TimeZone parameter

Tags: postgresql

I installed Postgresql 9.5.3 on windows, and picked "default locale" during the installation.

I believe that this has made my system TimeZone parameter default to my local timezone. I know that I can manually set the time zone using `set timezone`: [How to set timezone for Postgres psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779293/how-to-set-timezone-for-postgres-psql/11779417#11779417)

However, I would like my system TimeZone parameter to be the 'UTC' time zone, without having to set it manually. I looked up my `postgresql.conf` and replaced the `timezone = ...` line with `timezone = 'UTC'`, per this [link](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/use-timestamptz.html), but this does not seem to have worked.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how `timestamp with time zone` works. The timestamp is always stored **without** a time zone on the server. When _retrieving_ the data, the timestamp is adjusted to the **client's** time zone. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#AEN6159

Comment: Ok, but how come the statement `insert into table_name (date_col) Values ('2015-01-01 00:00:00')` results in something different depending on what the time zone of the database has been set to, and what does `set timezone` do then?

Comment: ok, reading the link this is I am guessing the relevant bit: `An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.`

Comment: I have edited my question, hopefully the premise of the question is correct now

Comment: what "does not seem to have worked"?.. how you see that?

Comment: what you see if you run `select now()`?..

Comment: On a completely new database initialised with default settings in pgadmin, I get `"2016-07-14 17:10:15.359946+10"`. If I run `set timezone = 'UTC'; select now();` I get `"2016-07-14 07:11:05.989+00"`

Comment: open a new connection to db and run `show timezone;` - what does it show?..

Comment: I assume you either edited wrong file or did not restart server... check `show config_file;` as well

Comment: thanks, that was it, I had to stop and start the service from pgadmin, not just quit and restart pgadmin