# How to change timezone of postgreSQL 9.5 on docker?

Tags: docker, postgresql-9.5

Default timezone is UTC.
But I want to change it to GMT+2.
I tried as below.

```
alter database governance set timezone = 'GMT+2';
```

But it does't work.

How can I manage it?

postgresql version is 9.5.
And it run on Docker.

Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

You should set timezone in your docker compose file (`TZ` and `PGTZ` are required):

```
postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
        TZ: 'GMT+2'
        PGTZ: 'GMT+2'
```

Reference: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/137#issuecomment-217064811

Comment: why does it require two keys to set?

Comment: @DularaMalindu `TZ` is for GNU/Linux and `PGTZ` is for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks! Works great for `postgres:14.1` image too.

Comment: For anyone with an issue use timezones using: select * from pg_timezone_names; Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/view-pg-timezone-names.html

Comment: What if I want to change the timezone for a running container ? I don't want to recreate it

Comment: @shellking4 have you tried this query `SET TIME ZONE 'GMT+2';`? ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6663848/2338672

Comment: @mortymacs thank you very much. It does change the timezone :))

Answer (score 16):

**For those who uses TZ and nothing happens**

the reason for me was that for the first time when container starts
it stores TZ variable in PG config in mapped volume. and after changing docker compose file to another TZ value it stays the same and looks like it doesn't work.
you should remove db first and then restart docker-compose

**in 2023**

if you are using some IDEs PG's client it could require additional info about your time zone

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48174902/1279329) is additional info of how it could be fixed

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, the logs were stuck on the wrong time zone for me

Answer (score 12):

To change timezone of you image try this:

```
docker run -it -e "TZ=GMT+2" postgres:alpine
```

docker-compose.yml

```
postgres:
  image: postgres:alpine
  environment: 
    - TZ=GMT+2
```

Comment: My explanation was insufficient.
I'm using docker-compose.yml. And I tried to add
    environment:
      TZ: GMT+2
But it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 6):

You have to specify the timezone in the `docker-compose.yml` file in this format:

```
postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
        TZ: "Europe/Madrid"
```