# Invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "Europe/Kyiv" Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, docker

I try to connect to Postgres  inside a docker container
as a result, I received `Invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "Europe/Kyiv"`

I've tried  to add  serverTimezone=Europe/Kyiv to the connect URL but its doest not work

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/db_name?serverTimezone=Europe/Kyiv
```

Also, I've tried

```
SET time zone 'Europe/Kyiv"
```

**UPD:**
My docker compose file

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
      PGTZ: 'Europe/Kyiv'
      TZ: 'Europe/Kyiv'

#      PGTZ: 'Europe/Kiev'
#      TZ: 'Europe/Kiev'
#
#      PGTZ: 'GMT+2'
#      TZ: 'GMT+2'
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

Comment: In https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/datetime-keywords.html there is `Europe/Kiev`

Comment: The spelling will probably depend upon the precise version of the timezone specs.

Comment: @qrsngky I've tried different option
I've added docker-compose file

Answer (score 1):

Solution - I've changed time zone on my OS to UTC

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem in `'Europe/Kyiv'`. Had similar issue with this, just leave old version of `'Europe/Kiev'`. Code you have provided should work just fine.

This issue is present on older versions of Postgres (before Postgres 15.1). For older versions of Postgres stay with old name of `'Europe/Kiev'`.

[Postgres Release Notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/15.1/#:%7E:text=the%20Europe/Kiev%20zone%20has%20been%20renamed%20to%20Europe/Kyiv)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting timezone as environment variable?

When using `docker-compose`

```yaml
postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
        TZ: 'Europe/Kyiv'
        PGTZ: 'Europe/Kyiv'
```

or when using `docker run`

```bash
docker run .... --env TZ=Europe/Kyiv --env PGTZ=Europe/Kyiv ....
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51697579/11847564)

Comment: I've tried this 
but it's not working I had the same error 

I've updated question  (I've added my docker-compose file)